# @ and ~ symbols unavailable in Xubuntu on VirtualBox with Norwegian keyboard

Tags: linux, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I`m running Xubuntu 12.10, Ubuntu 12.10 and Linux Mint 14 in VirtualBox 4.10 with Windows 7 as the host system. My keyboard is a Logitech G110 with a Norwegian layout, and I have configured the host system accordingly.

In all my virtual linux machines I am unable to type the @-symbol and the tilde (~) symbol. These are suppose to be mapped to AltGr+2 and AltGr+^ respectively (this would be different on US keyboards). Still, the British pound symbol and the American $ mapped to AltGr+3 and AltGr+4 respectively work fine.

I have tried adding an .Xmodmap-file with the line

```
keycode 113 = Mode_switch Multi_key
```

as suggested by some to fix an issue with AltGr not working at all, but with no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Posted using a US layout...)

Comment: And this occurs even when using a Norwegian layout on the guest machines?

Comment: Yes, it is when using a Norwegian layout I have this problem.

Comment: Because on my Xubuntu 12.10 guest I have the choice of 6 different Norwegian layouts and over a 100 keyboard models. Trying some different combinations might help.

Comment: Does "not working" mean no symbol appears, or the wrong symbol?

Comment: @oKtosiTe no symbol appears. (This time the @-symbol was copied, mouse style...)

Comment: Try this in `.Xmodmap`: `keycode 12 = 3 numbersign asciitilde dead_macron asciitilde`. According to `man xmodmap` the first `asciitilde` is important, but on cygwin the second is. (I currently have no native Linux to test...). Analog for 2-Key: `keycode 11 = 2 quotedbl at dead_macron at`

Comment: Update: After some testing I've found that my AltGr-key generates two keycodes when pressed: 37 and 108. I have also tested the same VBox setup on different machines without this problem showing up. But why on my wokstation? Could HP's SAM cause a problem like this? (I'm working remotely on a Proliant Blade running Win 7 Ent and connecting using a Win 7 thin HP client or a Win 7 HP desktop. The virtual machine is running on the blade. )